# Is allowing global CORS in my case security issue

Tags: rest, security, cors, haproxy

I have rest api which is publicly available with REST API key authentication, but I want to allow private network to access api without authentication. Is it safe to add global CORS
`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Note that I am doing authentication in haproxy:

```
acl private_ip src -m reg -i (^127\\.0\\.0\\.1)|(^10.*)|(^172\\.1[6-9].*)|(^172\\.2[0-9].*)|(^172\\.3[0-1].*)|(^192\\.168.*)|(^::1$)|(^[fF][cCdD])|(0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1)
```

I read that setting CORS "*" could cause some security issues in case when there is IP authentication, but as I am not sure how "src" IP address in haproxy is obtained I can't be sure if this security risk is present in my case?

Comment: Simply ask yourself this: if an attacker were able to be in the network and send requests from one of the allowed IP addresses, would it be bad if s/he could read the responses from your unauthenticated API endpoints? More about this in the section entitled _Abusing CORS without credentials_ in https://portswigger.net/research/exploiting-cors-misconfigurations-for-bitcoins-and-bounties

Comment: Thanks, this was very useful (and interesting) content on url you posted, I like explanations by example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is strongly recommended against to use IP authentication and a permissive CORS policy together.

CORS allows for script on a page served from one host to process a response from a call to a resource on another host when normally a well-behaved browser would stop script on the page from reading the response. For example where a page on *webserver.com* includes an AJAX call to a resource on *api-server.com*.

CORS is enforced by the browser, so if your attacker can make a call to your API then they are able to ignore your CORS header, and this is transitive to anything they can get another user to do by serving them a malicious page.

API authentication (whether by token or by IP) is a server-side protection that allows you to filter your response to the request. Consider the case where your attacker has access to your network. They can make a request to your API and your IP authentication lets them get the data. CORS is not the solution to that, but you of course secure your network well and only your users have access to it.

However, if the attacker controls a website (say, *compromised.example.com*) then they can send a user on your network a link to their page. When your user goes to the page, they are served a script that makes a call to your API. Because you permit the request based on IP, you provide the response.

This is where CORS comes in. If you have a header allowing '*' on your API responses, then the browser on your network will happily provide the requesting page (served from the attacker who is not on your network) with the response.

So the attacker has unauthenticated access to your API if they can get one of your network's users to browse to their malicious page and exfiltrate any responses that a user on your network can get.

Comment: [Brighter days ahead](https://github.com/WICG/local-network-access), though.

Comment: Thanks, very nice explanation, I never had a time to really dig into security issues related to CORS and most of the time it was more or less just allow "*" on API, but now I wanted to see how to finally make it right. I will just remove IP and leave token authentication and CORS I think it has to be "*" because it is public ip inside web application.